# Conduit Required in Commercial Building Panel?

Tags: electrical-panel

I am working on an old commercial (one level) building.  The old panel has some Romex and some 1/2" EMT running into the top of it (7 ft high at the top).  For the new branch circuits that I am pulling, will I be required to run EMT out of the top of panel and into ceiling (12 ft)? or can I just run the circuits out the top of the panel and staple Romex to a fixed board where the other circuits are stapled to? (not sure if it was ever inspected in the past)

thanks much - commercial installation of branch circuits is a little confusing in the code book as well as what structures qualify as "commercial".

Comment: Generally you want to see conduit in commercial. In particular cables need to be protected from damage.

Comment: This will very likely be jurisdiction dependent. Google your state/county/city (more specific the better but it varies) to find out what version of NEC you need to use (that can affect quite a few little details) and what local amendments (which will tell you if you need to use conduit for ordinary branch circuits or not). If you can't find the details online or they aren't clear, call the local permitting office and ask.

Comment: Generally either conduit or metal armored cable (AC or MC, etc.) are required in commercial occupancies.